# Params not showing in URL - Axios and Node

Tags: node.js, parameters, axios

I can't seem to find this issue with Node so I am asking for some help please.

I have params in my axios request and they won't show up in my URL. I have no idea why. It worked for a bit and then I made some changes for a different issue and now I can't get them to work again.

ROUTE:

```
router.route('/updatePasswordViaEmail/:email?').post((req,res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query.email)
    User.find({email: req.query.email})
```

CLIENT:

```
    axios.post('/updatePasswordViaEmail/', {
      params: {
        email: data.email
      },
    })
```

I get a 404 error because my route is looking for an email but the URL doesn't have it.

Here is my config file on the response:

```
config:
url: "/updatePasswordViaEmail/"
method: "post"
data: "{"params":{"email":"pjconnolly12@gmail.com"}}"
```

it shows the params, but still doesn't get added to the end of the URL

Please help...what am I missing!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing an empty body to your POST call.

```
axios.post('/updatePasswordViaEmail/', {}, {
  params: {
    email: data.email
  },
})
```

Note the empty data 2nd parameter.